# javascript "this" keyword works as expected in browser but not in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know I'm making a mistake here but I can't figure out what it is.

The following code (non-strict mode) works as I expect in a browser and outputs "hello" to the console.

```
function a() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}
var bar = "hello";
a();
```

But when I run it in node "undefined" is the output.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: There's nothing unexpected about this. You never define a property of `a` named `bar`.

Comment: Node modules bring their own scope  (when not executed as a script or in repl). Do you know *how* this works in the browser?

Comment: @EdCottrell - `this` doesn't refer to `a`, does it? (Why would it?)

Comment: I have tried this codes, and it print "hello" in node.

Comment: @nnnnnn it refers to the object in the scope of which it is used. That would be a function in this example, namely `a`.

Comment: @EdCottrell - That's very un-JavaScript-like. Are you sure that applies in Node (it wouldn't in the browser)? Normally `this` is set entirely dependent on how a function is called.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not sure what you mean. It definitely works that way in the browser.

Comment: @tsh If it is working, I suspect you're using Node's REPL. The code entered there isn't considered part of a module and is evaluated in the global scope. Try again with a file/module, and the result will change.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes, I was using REPL. I have tried another time with file, and it print "undefined".

Comment: @EdCottrell - It definitely does *not* work that way in the browser. The only way `this` would refer to the function `a` would be if you called it by saying `a.apply(a)` or `a.call(a)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn perhaps I'm not being precise enough. It refers to a given instance of `a`. I agree it doesn't refer to `a` itself.

Comment: @EdCottrell: The function is not called with `new` here. There is no "instance of `a`".

Comment: @EdCottrell Are you confusing it with a constructor call?

Comment: @self: There is no global variable here. It's declared local by `var`.

Comment: There being a consensus that I was missing something, I just [did some reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and broadened my horizons. Apparently, I misunderstood how `this` works when a function is merely invoked and not instantiated as an object. I learned something tonight! This is why I love Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both, the browser and Node, `this` inside the function refers to the global object (in this case). Every global variable is a property of the global object.

The code works in the browser because the "default scope" is the global scope. `var bar` therefore declares a global variable, which becomes a property of the global object.

However in Node, every file is considered to be a **module**. Each module has its own scope. In this case,`var bar` does **not** create a global variable, but a *module scoped* variable. Since there is no *global* variable `bar`, `this.bar` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems codes run in `node` is wrapped into a function. Something like the following codes:

```
(function () {
  function a() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
  var bar = "hello";   
  a(); 
}());
```

You may try this codes in browesr, and it also print "undefined".

You may try `console.log(arguments);` and `return` statements out of any function in node, and see what happened.

```
console.log(arguments);
return;
console.log("this will not be printed.");
```

Will output:

```
{ '0': {},
  '1':
   { [Function: require]
     resolve: [Function],
   ....
  '4': .... }
```

Also, you may try following codes:

```
var another = require("./another.js");

function a() {
    console.log(this.bar);
    console.log(this.baz);
}

bar = "hello";
a();
```

And in `another.js`:

```
baz = "world"; // no var here
```

You will saw both `hello`, and, `world` be printed.